# Как поменять имя проекта вручную?

Tags: android, файлы, struct

Разбираюсь со структурой файлов. Хочу переименовать уже имеющийся проект (корневой пакет остается прежним) вручную. Подключен GIT. Меня инетересует не только отображение на устройстве но и все упоминания в студии.
В каких файлах содержится имя проекта?

Answer (score 2):

- Если речь о имени проекта, отображаемым в заголовке окна и над деревом файлов - это просто имя папки, в которой он расположен.
- Чтобы сменить имя приложения, выводимое пользователю под иконкой, в настройках  и т.п. - это в манифесте, атрибут andorid:label тега application. Студия при создании проекта выносит его в ресурсы как app_name.
- Сменить имя пакета приложения - сменить значение applicationId в gradle модуля app.
- Если хотите сменить имена пакетов внутри проекта - выделяйте в дереве нужный пакет и жмите crtl+F6. Только закомитьтесь/сделайте копию, иногда это может вызвать проблемы.

Даже не знаю что еще может иметься в виду под именем проекта, если не ответил на ваш вопрос - уточните его